# udev without LAN access?

Tags: debian, udev, lan

I am running a RPi 4b with Raspbian (Bullseye), Logitech Media Server (LMS) 8.2.0 and Squeezelite 1.9.9. For automated startup of the Squeezelite process whenever a certain USB device is connected, I have defined the following `udev` rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{PRODUCT}=="154e/300a/3", RUN+="/usr/bin/DAC_start.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{PRODUCT}=="154e/300a/3", RUN+="/usr/bin/DAC_stop.sh"
```

This is my `DAC_start.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
######### DAC_start.sh #########
date >> /tmp/udev.log
echo "Starting Squeezelite" >> /tmp/udev.log
sleep 5s
/usr/bin/squeezelite -o hw:CARD=ND8006,DEV=0 -D -n MediaPlayer -d all=debug -f /tmp/sq.log | at now
###############################
```

This is my `DAC_stop.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
######### DAC_stop.sh #########
date >> /tmp/udev.log
echo "Stopping Squeezelite ..." >> /tmp/udev.log
pkill squeezelite
###############################
```

Both scripts work fine when I execute them manually (both as pi and root): Squeezelite successfully connects to the LMS and USB device, music can be played.
The `udev` rules also work and get fired when I connect my USB DAC (which I can see from the log files).
However, when squeezelite gets started by `udev`, squeezelite seems to be unable to connect to my LMS server which is on the same LAN, actually on the same machine. This is the Squeezelite logfile (I think the more important messages are at the very bottom, but i copied all messages for your convience in case I am overlooking something):

```
/usr/bin/squeezelite -o hw:CARD=ND8006,DEV=0 -D -n MediaPlayer -d all=debug -f /tmp/sq.log
[16:22:50.362611] stream_init:454 init stream
[16:22:50.362971] stream_init:455 streambuf size: 2097152
[16:22:50.376806] output_init_alsa:936 init output
[16:22:50.377007] output_init_alsa:976 requested alsa_buffer: 40 alsa_period: 4 format: any mmap: 1
[16:22:50.377081] output_init_common:360 outputbuf size: 3528000
[16:22:50.377333] output_init_common:384 idle timeout: 0
[16:22:50.410804] test_open:301 sample rate 1536000 not supported
[16:22:50.410907] test_open:301 sample rate 1411200 not supported
[16:22:50.411049] test_open:301 sample rate 32000 not supported
[16:22:50.411085] test_open:301 sample rate 24000 not supported
[16:22:50.411118] test_open:301 sample rate 22500 not supported
[16:22:50.411151] test_open:301 sample rate 16000 not supported
[16:22:50.411184] test_open:301 sample rate 12000 not supported
[16:22:50.411216] test_open:301 sample rate 11025 not supported
[16:22:50.411249] test_open:301 sample rate 8000 not supported
[16:22:50.411330] output_init_common:426 supported rates: 768000 705600 384000 352800 192000 176400 96000 88200 48000 44100
[16:22:50.500287] output_init_alsa:1002 memory locked
[16:22:50.500456] output_init_alsa:1008 glibc detected using mallopt
[16:22:50.501072] output_init_alsa:1026 unable to set output sched fifo: Operation not permitted
[16:22:50.501080] output_thread:685 open output device: hw:CARD=ND8006,DEV=0
[16:22:50.501156] decode_init:153 init decode
[16:22:50.502046] alsa_open:354 opening device at: 44100
[16:22:50.502132] register_dsd:908 using dsd to decode dsf,dff
[16:22:50.502166] register_alac:549 using alac to decode alc
[16:22:50.502198] register_faad:663 using faad to decode aac
[16:22:50.502229] register_vorbis:385 using vorbis to decode ogg
[16:22:50.502325] register_opus:328 using opus to decode ops
[16:22:50.502361] register_flac:336 using flac to decode ogf,flc
[16:22:50.502392] register_pcm:483 using pcm to decode aif,pcm
[16:22:50.502433] register_mad:423 using mad to decode mp3
[16:22:50.502463] decode_init:194 include codecs:  exclude codecs:
[16:22:50.503117] alsa_open:425 opened device hw:CARD=ND8006,DEV=0 using format: S32_LE sample rate: 44100 mmap: 1
[16:22:50.503159] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:22:50.503272] alsa_open:516 buffer: 40 period: 4 -> buffer size: 1764 period size: 441
[16:22:50.503349] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:22:55.504955] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:22:55.505246] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:00.510091] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:00.510360] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:05.515053] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:05.515329] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:10.519882] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:10.520185] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:15.528387] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:15.528659] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:20.535819] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:20.536007] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:25.541079] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:25.541333] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:30.549470] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:30.549640] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:35.559568] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:35.559857] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:40.568356] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:40.568646] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:45.576730] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:45.577009] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:50.586202] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:50.586502] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:23:55.596574] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:23:55.596872] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:00.604989] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:00.605269] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:05.615978] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:05.616278] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:10.625168] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:10.625472] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:15.633952] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:15.634246] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:20.642357] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:20.642648] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:25.650821] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:25.651113] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:30.662745] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:30.663055] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:35.670289] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:35.670566] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:40.674134] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:40.674460] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:45.679650] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:45.679984] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:50.689070] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:50.689366] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:24:55.697415] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:24:55.697709] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:25:00.705845] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:25:00.706128] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:25:05.714279] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:25:05.714583] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:25:10.723306] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:25:10.723601] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
[16:25:15.728709] discover_server:795 sending discovery
[16:25:15.728977] discover_server:799 error sending disovery
```

It seems as if Squeezelite, when started by `udev`, has no access to the LAN? I also tried starting Squeezelite with the `-s 192.168.1.20` parameter (which is the IP of my LMS) -- but without success. It still cannot connect to the LMS server. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

*I used the approach described above on an RPi with piCore OS (which is a Tiny Core Linux distribution), and it worked like a charm...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested by @dirkt, starting Squeezelite by `udev` as a process is not a good idea: LAN access under `udev` is somehow limited, and the process will get killed after some time anyway. It is the preferred way to start Squeezelite as a service.

To do so, the `udev` rules need to be defined as follows:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-DAC.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="bind", ENV{PRODUCT}=="154e/300a/3", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="DAC_sql_start.service"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="unbind", ENV{PRODUCT}=="154e/300a/3", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="DAC_sql_stop.service"
```

Note that I used the `bind` resp. `unbind` action for the USB device which (in my case) proved to be more robust than the `add` resp. `remove`. Also, I had to put `ENV{...}` around the `SYSTEMD_WANTS` for a reason I don't understand...

The corresponding services need to be defined as follows:

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/DAC_sql_start.service
[Unit]
Description=Squeezelite by DAC script (start)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/DAC_sql.sh start
```

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/DAC_sql_stop.service
[Unit]
Description=Squeezelite by DAC script (stop)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/DAC_sql.sh stop
```

I modified the shell script `DAC_sql.sh` as follows:

```bsh
# cat /usr/bin/DAC_sql.sh
#!/bin/sh
######### DAC_sql.sh #########
#sleep 5s
case $1 in
    "start")
        #date >> /tmp/DAC.log
        #echo "Starting Squeezelite..." >> /tmp/DAC.log
        /usr/bin/squeezelite -o hw:CARD=ND8006,DEV=0 -s 127.0.0.1 -D -n MediaPlayer #-d all=debug -f /tmp/sq.log;;
        ;;
    "stop")
        #date >> /tmp/DAC.log
        #echo "Stopping Squeezelite..." >> /tmp/DAC.log
        systemctl stop DAC_sql_start
        ;;
esac
##############################
```

It now works as expected: Whenever the USB device is switched on (bound into the system), Squeezelite is started as a service. When the USB device is switched off (unbound from the system), the Squeezelite service is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

From `man udev`:

> RUN{type}
>
> [...]
>
> Add a program to the list of programs to be executed after processing all the rules for a specific event, depending on type:
>
> This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks. Running an event process for a long period of time may block all further events for this or a dependent device.
>
> Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not appropriate for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed after the event handling has           finished.

So even if you could get it to access LAN (which is probably difficult, processes run by udev are in a somewhat limited environment) it is not the right way to start and stop something like squeezelite.

Try for example a systemd service as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464973/3554119).

Comment: I have now created the `systemd` services and changed the `udev` rules as follows:
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{PRODUCT}=="154e/300a/3", TAG+="systemd", SYSTEMD_WANTS="DAC_sql_start.service"` and `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{PRODUCT}=="154e/300a/3", TAG+="systemd", SYSTEMD_WANTS="DAC_sql_stop.service"`. 
It works fine when I manually start the services. But somehow the services don't get automatically started by `udev` anymore when I connect the USB device. Something wrong with how I changed the `udev` rules?

Comment: There's probably something wrong, and debugging this is no fun. Try to manually restart `udevd` with something like `udevd --debug` or `udevd --debug-trace --verbose`, and see if you can figure something out.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt for guiding me into the right direction! I was able to debug the ˋudevˋ rule and have it up and running now. I will provide a more detailed answer to my question later in the day.